# How do I unit test my ASP.NET 5 code on non-Windows platforms?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core

I'd like to add unit tests to an ASP.NET 5 (i.e. [vNext](http://asp.net/vnext)) project I'm writing and running on OS X. Is there any platform-agnostic facility in the new framework for running unit tests? If not, what are my options (running nunit on mono, for example)? Both the [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/nunit/) and [nunit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=installation&r=2.2) sites mention the test suite being bundled with mono, but, then again, both those pages appear to be outdated.

Answer (score 4):

For [DNX](https://github.com/aspnet/home) versions from `beta4` and up, the open-source [xUnit.net project](https://xunit.github.io/) supports unit testing for DNX projects. To summarize [the documentation](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html):

Include the xUnit NuGet packages in your `project.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.1.0-rc1-build3168",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-beta5-build169"
},
"commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
}
```

Then, given a class in your project folder containing tests, like this:

```cs
using Xunit;

namespace MyFirstDnxUnitTests
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void PassingTest()
        {
            Assert.Equal(4, Add(2, 2));
        }

        [Fact]
        public void FailingTest()
        {
            Assert.Equal(5, Add(2, 2));
        }

        int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

Running the `dnx test` command (note that this command was specified in `project.json`) will run the tests.